# Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS apt problem

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

To **16.04** LTS.

I ran the command `do-release-upgrade` but I got this error :

```
The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
```

So I did a `apt full-upgrade` cause `apt-get dist-upgrade` didn't find any updates followed by `apt-get update`

And than I ran the release upgrade and I got hit by the same error.

P.S : The version of ubuntu now is like the first time 14.04 LTS, so no 14.04.**X**

What should I do ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the entire contents of your file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

The repo shows the needed version of `apt`. You can download it here https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt. Then install it using `dpkg`.

```
dpkg -i filename.deb #replace filename.deb with the actual file name
```

Comment: and how can I do that in command ?

Comment: `dpkg -i filename.deb` will install it. replace filename.deb with the actual file name. I'm not sure how to download it by command line possibly `get`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS

To upgrade on a Desktop system, you will need to do the following from GUI:

Open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Settings.

Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".
Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version" if you are using 14.04, set it to "long-term support versions" if you are using 15.10 LTS.
Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager" (without the quotes) into the command box.
Software Updater should open up and tell you: New distribution release '16.04 LTS' is available.
Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

To upgrade on a server system:

Install the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed.

Make sure the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades is set to normal if you are using 14.04 LTS if you are using 14.04 LTS.
Launch the upgrade tool with the command

`sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Follow the on-screen instructions.
Note that the server upgrade will use GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of dropped connection problems.

There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Please ensure you have network connectivity to one of the official mirrors or to a locally accessible mirror and follow the instructions above.

OR

Follow this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts